# Wordpress Not updating - No Cache Plugins, Admin sees updates

Tags: updates, cache

I have no cache plugins active, I have put CloudFlare in development mode and also tried pausing it. None of these work. Somehow there is something cached on Wordpress side and it does not show the updated site for regular visitors.

When I am logged in as admin, I can see the new updates like new comments replies, or any site changes. But, when I visit as a normal user, I do not see them. Also, one strange thing is that the changes get applied after sometime like few hours or so. I have no idea, whats going on. So, weird. 
I have the most latest Wordpress 4.9.8.

Please help,

Comment: how did you installed the wordpress? manually or with some third party application?

Comment: it was automatic in cPanel.

Comment: check for MU plugins

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue. One of our advertising vendor enabled caching on their end as we gave them Cloudflare access for the platform. So, please double check with all your vendors on caching. It is not a technical issue with Wordpress.